# Getting phpmyadmin to work with new localhost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed mysql and phpmyadmin on my system(ubuntu) and used to access `phpmyadmin` as `"localhost/phpmyadmin"`.

But then for reason I changed my `"localhost"` name to `"localhost.shop"` and tired to access `phpmyadmin` as `"localhost.shop/phpmyadmin"`, where is shows

> 404 Page Not Found;

and when using `"localhost/phpmyadmin"`, it shows

> 500 Internal Server Error

How to rectify this problem.
I am using nginx.

Comment: Look into server logfile. 500 is a internal server error

Comment: What happens when you just hit "localhost.shop"?  do you see the desired page?